# Help with URL argument token

Tags: tokens

I'm trying to use tokens in the Linked Field module to link a field in one content type to another content type. I'm also using Pathauto.

So I want to link a field in URL `/type/subtype/pagetitle` to destination URL `/type/subtype`.

I've tried `[current-page:url:args:first]/[current-page:url:args:second]` but the second token doesn't work and the resulting URL is just `/type`.

I've tried using the `[node:field_nameofsubtype]` token but that results in `/type/Sub Type` instead of the `/type/subtype` generated by my Pathauto.

Surely it isn't that hard to use tokens to just move one step up the URL tree but I can't find it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Done it!!  This works anyway:

```
[current-page:url:args:first]/[current-page:url:args:value:1]
```